# Obtain recursive filename with boost library

Tags: boost, filenames

I tried to obtain filenames recursively using the following function. But I only got a subfolder name (like that: /media/username). To understand the problem, I wrote the path value to /media/username instead of /media, but this time I couldn't get any filename. Does the /media directory have a special rule? If yes, how can I overcome this? If no, why can't I get the filenames?

The obtain function like below:

```
void obtain_filenames()
{
    for(const auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator("/media"))
        m_filenames.push_back(p.path().string());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no special rule. You ask for the filenames, so you get them. If you want full paths, you can do that:

```
for(const auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(directory))
    paths.push_back(fs::absolute(p.path()));
```

Note that this gives you the entire path (so if you used ".", you might get "/home/purgoufr/.bashrc", not "./bashrc"). If you don't want that, look at `make_relative", e.g.:

```
    paths.push_back(directory / fs::relative(p.path(), directory));
```

> Side notes:
>
> - keep in mind permission errors may break your iterator loop (see `fs::directory_options::pop_on_error`)
> - blindly iterating any directory recursively could lead to (security) issues. In this case you could run out of memory, end up as an infinite loop (see `fs::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink`) etc.

### Demo

Showing some of the improvements mentioned and more:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28cdb76be485cf35)**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
using Paths = std::vector<fs::path>;

Paths obtain_filenames(fs::path base, size_t max)
{
    Paths paths;
    for(const auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(base, fs::directory_options::pop_on_error))
    {
        // paths.push_back(fs::absolute(p.path().string()));
        paths.push_back(base / fs::relative(p.path(), base));
        if (paths.size() >= max)
            break;
    }

    return paths;
}

#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (auto arg : std::vector(argv + 1, argv + argc)) {
        for (auto const& path : obtain_filenames(arg, 5)) {
            std::cout << path << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

E.g. when run with './sotest ../stackoverflow/*/' on my system prints

```
"../stackoverflow/asio/CMakeLists.txt"
"../stackoverflow/asio/Service.h"
"../stackoverflow/asio/Acceptor.cpp"
"../stackoverflow/asio/main.cpp"
"../stackoverflow/asio/Service.cpp"
"../stackoverflow/boost-dll-example/.devcontainer"
"../stackoverflow/boost-dll-example/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json"
"../stackoverflow/boost-dll-example/.devcontainer/Dockerfile"
"../stackoverflow/boost-dll-example/.git"
"../stackoverflow/boost-dll-example/.git/info"
"../stackoverflow/bucket/5f7d8fe7-be61-4182-9553-8aa4dceefd36"
"../stackoverflow/bucket/5f7d8fe7-be61-4182-9553-8aa4dceefd36/q.png"
"../stackoverflow/bucket/59caf141-803d-41dc-b7b0-fd6601e88295"
"../stackoverflow/bucket/0605ef7a-0bcf-4b00-a3fe-ef2560758008"
"../stackoverflow/bucket/718b317d-bc98-4012-a2c9-d1453edf7771"
"../stackoverflow/CMakeFiles/CMakeRuleHashes.txt"
"../stackoverflow/CMakeFiles/sotest.dir"
"../stackoverflow/CMakeFiles/sotest.dir/CXX.includecache"
"../stackoverflow/CMakeFiles/sotest.dir/depend.make"
"../stackoverflow/CMakeFiles/sotest.dir/DependInfo.cmake"
"../stackoverflow/cppcoro/args.cake"
"../stackoverflow/cppcoro/.clang-format"
"../stackoverflow/cppcoro/config.cake"
"../stackoverflow/cppcoro/.git"
"../stackoverflow/cppcoro/.git/hooks"
"../stackoverflow/cpp-sort/build"
"../stackoverflow/cpp-sort/build/cmake_install.cmake"
"../stackoverflow/cpp-sort/build/compile_commands.json"
"../stackoverflow/cpp-sort/build/Catch2-build"
"../stackoverflow/cpp-sort/build/Catch2-build/CTestTestfile.cmake"
"../stackoverflow/detail/yield.hpp"
"../stackoverflow/eos-portable-archive/readme"
"../stackoverflow/eos-portable-archive/change_log.txt"
"../stackoverflow/eos-portable-archive/tutorial"
"../stackoverflow/eos-portable-archive/tutorial/code"
"../stackoverflow/eos-portable-archive/tutorial/code/tutorial_pba_10b.cpp"
"../stackoverflow/eventpp/.gitignore"
"../stackoverflow/eventpp/license"
"../stackoverflow/eventpp/.github"
"../stackoverflow/eventpp/.github/workflows"
"../stackoverflow/eventpp/.github/workflows/main.yml"
"../stackoverflow/fmt/cmake_install.cmake"
"../stackoverflow/fmt/support"
"../stackoverflow/fmt/support/rtd"
"../stackoverflow/fmt/support/rtd/theme"
"../stackoverflow/fmt/support/rtd/theme/theme.conf"
"../stackoverflow/msghub/build"
"../stackoverflow/msghub/build/compile_commands.json"
"../stackoverflow/msghub/build/examples"
"../stackoverflow/msghub/build/examples/cmake_install.cmake"
"../stackoverflow/msghub/build/examples/server"
"../stackoverflow/mymsg/.git"
"../stackoverflow/mymsg/.git/hooks"
"../stackoverflow/mymsg/.git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample"
"../stackoverflow/mymsg/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample"
"../stackoverflow/mymsg/.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample"
"../stackoverflow/mysql/.gitignore"
"../stackoverflow/mysql/Jamfile"
"../stackoverflow/mysql/tools"
"../stackoverflow/mysql/tools/user_project_find_package"
"../stackoverflow/mysql/tools/user_project_find_package/CMakeLists.txt"
"../stackoverflow/networking-ts-impl/.git"
"../stackoverflow/networking-ts-impl/.git/logs"
"../stackoverflow/networking-ts-impl/.git/logs/HEAD"
"../stackoverflow/networking-ts-impl/.git/logs/refs"
"../stackoverflow/networking-ts-impl/.git/logs/refs/remotes"
"../stackoverflow/nghttp2/Makefile.am"
"../stackoverflow/nghttp2/makemanpages"
"../stackoverflow/nghttp2/help2rst.py"
"../stackoverflow/nghttp2/fedora"
"../stackoverflow/nghttp2/fedora/spdylay.spec"
"../stackoverflow/obj/testera.o"
"../stackoverflow/obj/testerb.o"
"../stackoverflow/pfr/meta"
"../stackoverflow/pfr/meta/libraries.json"
"../stackoverflow/pfr/test"
"../stackoverflow/pfr/test/compile-fail"
"../stackoverflow/pfr/test/compile-fail/non_aggregate.cpp"
... and so on
```

Comment: Added a live demo with some of the fixes mentioned, and helpful example output. Error handling could be improved on the `make_relative` call, but I leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I came across an interesting situation. Just to be sure, I compiled and ran the same code you posted. But the same problem persisted, I mean, it just returned a subfolder name. I ran my out file many times, but the result did not change. Finally, I manually opened the disk file (/media/username/..) and entered the subfolders. When I ran it after this step it started seeing all subfolders.

Comment: Although I don't understand why, it shows correctly after opening the directory manually, but if I don't open it manually after inserting the disk, the problem persists. If you have a linux OS, can you try to run the code you sent after inserting any usb disk, by giving the "/media" parameter?

Comment: Oh. You're probably missing the mount steps. Filesystems aren't (always) mounted automatically. That's not related to the code, so I would suggest to ask/search on unix.stackechange.com or perhaps askubuntu.com